# query and subquery on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has the following columns

```
PatientID | DateOfService | CPTCode | Units
```

I need a query that will essentially find all rows where `CPTCode = "some value"`. Additionally, for each of those rows, it will find all other rows where there is a matching `PatientID` and `DateOfService`.

Is there one single query that can accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MumbaiMann If you have tried whatever then please share with use with the same. Because it will help us to understand your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a self join:

```
select b.*
  from yourtable a
  left join
       yourtable b
    on (    a.Patient_ID = b.Patient_ID
        and a.DateOfService = b.DateOfService)
 where a.CPTCode = "some value"
```

this will return all rows that have "some value" and all other rows with matching DateOfService and Patient_ID

Comment: why use a join? jus a subquery will do!!

Comment: you're right. at first i thought he wanted the records with `"some value"`, i.e. `a.*` as well. only then i realised they were included in the second set (`b.*`) as well anyway.

Answer (score 1):

something like this: ?

`select PatientID,DateOfservice,CPTCode,Units from table where CPTCode in(select CPTCode from table where CPTCode=<some_value> )`

: Teh subquery select CPTCode which matches with some values then other attributes are selected based on the subquery

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting how will you manage PatientID & DateOfService, as you said you want 
CPTCode = "some value" & matching PatientID and DateOfService. Seems meaningless. How can you match Id & Date ? Still this might help you out.

```
SELECT 
PatientID,
DateOfService,
CPTCode,
Units
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
CPTCode = "some value" AND PatientID = DateOfService
```

Comment: i suspect he wants to filter on a treatment or something and wants to know what else those patients received on that day.

Comment: May be he want to join table on self & select based on the next & previous condition as you specified. Ask him to come to earth & then ask :)